# function inside Scriptblock unable to understand

Tags: function, powershell, orchestration, scriptblock

I am having issues trying to understand how to integrate a function on a scriptblock.   The reason why I need the scriptblock is because I want to run a powershell script in orchestrator unless someone can help me how can I run a working customized function in orchestrator.  The function I want to run I got it from another site but I changed the name of the variables.

```
Function Get-RDPStatus {
    param (
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    begin {
        $SelectHash = @{
         'Property' = @('Name','ADObject','DNSEntry','PingResponse','RDPConnection')
        }
    }

    process {
        foreach ($CurrentComputer in $ComputerName) {
            # Create new Hash
            $HashProps = @{
                'Name' = $CurrentComputer
                'ADObject' = $false
                'DNSEntry' = $false
                'RDPConnection' = $false
                'PingResponse' = $false
            }

            # Perform Checks
            switch ($true)
            {

                {([adsisearcher]"samaccountname=$CurrentComputer`$").findone()} {$HashProps.ADObject = $true}
                {$(try {[system.net.dns]::gethostentry($CurrentComputer)} catch {})} {$HashProps.DNSEntry = $true}
                {$(try {$socket = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient($CurrentComputer, 3389);if ($socket.Connected) {$true};$socket.Close()} catch {})} {$HashProps.RDPConnection = $true}
                {Test-Connection -ComputerName $CurrentComputer -Quiet -Count 1} {$HashProps.PingResponse = $true}
                Default {}
            }

            # Output object
            New-Object -TypeName 'PSCustomObject' -Property $HashProps | Select-Object @SelectHash
        }
    }

    end {
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question.

Comment: he didn't, well, the only thing you need to do is call your function, after defining it, so and this to the bottom `Get-RDPStatus someinput`

Comment: Actually the question is how can i add this function to work on a scriptblock.  I tried to use the suggestion below by prageet but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your function to a PS script and create a script block from it.

```
$script = Get-Content -Path "C:\Folder\YourFunctionScript.ps1"
$ScriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create($script)
```

You can simply invoke it thru `invoke-command`

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

Comment: If I understood it correct, the OP want to integrate this function to a script block. Now, seeing back with your comment it could also be perceived as he want to integrate his function to an existing script block ! Let's wait for more clarity !

Comment: Prageet this is what i have used:

$Servers = 'server02'

$script = Get-Content -Path "D:\Scripts\Test-RDP.ps1"
$ScriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create($script)

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock

Get-RDPStatus -ComputerName $Servers | Export-Csv c:\temp\Post-Patching-Runbook.csv


Not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Where do you want to call the Get-RDPStatus method ? What is it you are really trying to do..?

Comment: This link explain how to run a powershell script in System Center Orchestrator which is what im trying to do.

https://automys.com/library/asset/powershell-system-center-orchestrator-practice-template

Im having trouble trying to run run that function.